# mod_rewrite issues and php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to convert my app links, so that a link like this:

```
http://localhost/index.php?id=13&category=Uncategorized&title=just-a-link
```

gets converted to this:

```
http://localhost/13/Uncategorized/just-a-test
```

so far I was able to do it using:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?id=$1&category=$2&title=$3 [QSA,L]
```

but that completely breaks links to css and other files as it redirects every request with query to index.php

so I changed it slightly so that it only runs when the first query is a number:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([0-9]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?id=$1&category=$2&title=$3 [QSA,L]
```

this one doesn't break css and js files, however when you go to the link for example `http://localhost/13/cat/test` then try to go to another link like `http://localhost/19/Uncategorized/something` **by clicking on it inside the previous page** it will instead redirect you to something like `http://localhost/13/Uncategorized/19/Uncategorized/just-a-test`

How do I achieve what I described without any of these weird side effects??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ /index.php?id=$1&category=$2&title=$3 [QSA,L]
```

And add this code to your `html <header>`:

```
<base href="/">
```

OR

```
<base href="http://www.domain.com/">
```

To fix relative css and js links

Comment: It worked! but is there any way to skip that html part and yet achieve that same result?

Comment: No way, because you change the relative path to all links included. But You can also use only absolute links... or use `index.php` in `/A/B/C/` folder...